# Annihilator of an element is the entire ring implies the element is $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I am currently reading the chapter on finitely-generated modules over PIDs in Jacobson's Basic Algebra and at several points he uses the property that if the annihilator of an element $x$ of the module (i.e. the elements $r$ of the base ring $R$ s.t. $rx=0$) is the entire base ring $R$, then the element is zero (i.e. $\text{ann}(x)=R\Rightarrow x=0$). I seem to have missed the part where he actually proves this or states why it is true, so I would like to ask what the reason for this might be in this specific case (finitely-generated modules over PIDs) and whether it holds in more general cases (non-finitely-generated modules over more general rings).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough to assume that the ring has identity element (and the module is unitary: $1x=x$).

Then in particular for $1\in R$ we get $0=1x=x$.

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple, but it kept eluding me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What if the ring is non-unital? Can you comment on this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4598397/is-0-the-only-element-whose-annihilator-is-the-whole-ring