# Is 0 the only element whose annihilator is the whole ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, banach-algebras

Let $R\neq \{0\}$ be a **non-unital** ring, where the multiplication is not everywhere zero, meaning there exist some nonzero elements $a,b\in R$ such that $ab\neq 0$.

> Question 1: If $a\in R\setminus \{0\}$ is such that its left annihilator is the entire ring:
> $$\text{Ann}_R(a):=\left\{r\in R: ra=0\right\}=R$$
> Can we conclude $a=0$?

> Question 2: Is the answer the same for **non-unital** Banach algebras?

The difficulty here is we don't have invertible elements, as there is no identity element in the ring/algebra.

Comment: If by trivial you mean $R=\{0\}$, then a counterexample is the ring satisfying $xy=0$ for every $x,y\in R$. Sometimes such ring is called "zero ring" or "ring of square zero".

Comment: @2ndYearFreshman Can there be other counterexamples? I just updated my question and excluded this situation.

Comment: Over any field the algebra $A$ generated by $\{a,b,c\}$ with every product zero except for $ac=b$ is associative since the product of 3 elements (no matter the order) is zero, also $cx=0,\forall x\in A$ and $c\neq 0$.

Comment: My guess is that you can also turn this algebra into a Banach algebra by considering it over the field of real numbers and defining $||x_1a+x_2b+x_3c||=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$ but it would be good to check.

Comment: @2ndYearFreshman Thanks! Building on your example, it seems it should work for all infinitely dimensional Banach algebra. Let $A\neq\{0\}$ be an inf-dim Banach space with a Hamel basis $H$. Define all products of basis elements zero, except for $a,b\in H$, which we can define it to be $ab=\alpha\cdot c$, where $c\in H$ and $\alpha$ is a scaler, such that $\|\alpha\cdot c\|\leq \|a\|\|b\|$. Then all other basis elements are zero divisors of the whole space.

Comment: Seems that $||x||=sup |x_i|$ may work as the desired norm and your extension is the one I had on mind.

Comment: @2ndYearFreshman Now that I think about it, it seems we need an extra condition: the closure of the subspace spanned by $H\setminus \{a,b\}$ cannot contain $a$ or $b$. Otherwise, the multiplication such defined won't be continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition you ask for is stronger than being a left zero divisor. I would prefer to call it something else. How about left annihilator (of $R$)?

For another example then, take a non-principal ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ with $1\not \in I$, and an element $x\in I$. Then consider $R'=I/(x)I$. E.g. $(x,y)/(x^2,xy)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect better terminology. Can you elaborate more on your example of $R'$? Which element is the $a$? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I suspect Joshua Tilley meant $R'=I/((x)I)$. Then for any $r\in I$, we have $xr \in (x)I$, which means $[x][r]=0$ in $R'$ for all $[r]\in R'$. In the specific example, $x$ times any polynomial vanishes in $(x,y)/(x^2,xy)$.

Comment: @Milten But in $R'$, $[x]=0$. Isn't it? Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: @user760 No, $x\notin (x)I$ (since $1\notin I$), so $[x]\ne 0$ in $R’$.

Comment: @Milten Thanks. I see